# Multiple Definitions Error of Global Arrays

Tags: c++

I am attempting to compile my c++ code, and I continue getting the error:

```
/tmp/ccEsZppG.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `mailboxes'
/tmp/ccEZq43v.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
/tmp/ccEsZppG.o:(.bss+0xc0): multiple definition of `threads'
/tmp/ccEZq43v.o:(.bss+0xc0): first defined here
/tmp/ccEsZppG.o:(.bss+0x120): multiple definition of `semaphores'
/tmp/ccEZq43v.o:(.bss+0x120): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here is my code:

addem.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include "mailbox.h"


using namespace std;

void *sumUp(void *arg);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  int numThreads, minThreads, maxInt, minInt;
  if (argc < 3) {
    cout << "Error: Need three arguments" << endl;
    return 1;
  }

  numThreads = atoi(argv[1]);
  maxInt = atoi(argv[2]);
  minThreads = 1;
  minInt = 1;

  if (numThreads < 1) {
    cout << "Cannot work with less than one thread\n"
         << "It's okay but do better next time!\n"
         << "We'll work with 1 thread this time.\n";
    numThreads = minThreads;
  } else if (numThreads > MAXTHREAD) {
    cout << "Sorry, the max for threads is 10.\n"
         << "We'll work with 10 threads this time.\n";
    numThreads = MAXTHREAD;
  }

  if (maxInt < 1) {
    cout << "What do you want me to do? I can't count backwards!\n"
         << "I can barely count forwards! Let's make the max number\n"
         << "be 1 to save time\n";
    maxInt = minInt;
  }

  struct msg outgoingMail[numThreads];
  int divider = maxInt / numThreads;
  int count = 1;

  //initialize arrays (mailboxes, semaphores)
  for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++) {
    sem_init(&semaphores[i], 0, 1);
    outgoingMail[i].iSender = 0;
    outgoingMail[i].type = RANGE;
    outgoingMail[i].value1 = count;
    count = count + divider;

    if (i = numThreads - 1) {
      outgoingMail[i].value2 = maxInt;
    } else {
      outgoingMail[i].value2 = count;
    }
  }

  for (int message = 0; message < numThreads; message++) {
    SendMsg(message+1, outgoingMail[message]);
  }
  int thread;
  for (thread = 0; thread <= numThreads; thread++) {
    pthread_create(&threads[thread], NULL, &sumUp, (void *)(intptr_t)(thread+1));
  }

  struct msg incomingMsg;
  int total = 0;
  for (thread = 0; thread < numThreads; thread++) {
    RecvMsg(0, incomingMsg);

    total = total + incomingMsg.value1;
  }

  cout << "The total for 1 to " << maxInt << " using "
       << numThreads << " threads is " << total << endl;

  return 0;
}

void *sumUp(void *arg) {

  int index,total;

  index = (intptr_t)arg;
  struct msg message;

  RecvMsg(index, message);

  message.iSender = index;
  message.type = ALLDONE;

  total = 0;
  for (int i = message.value1; i <= message.value2; i++) {
    total += i;
  }
  SendMsg(0, message);
  
  return (void *) 0;
}
```

mailbox.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "mailbox.h"

using namespace std;

int SendMsg(int iTo, struct msg &Msg) {

  if (safeToCall(iTo)) {
    cout << "Error calling SendMsg" << endl;
    return 1;
  }

  sem_wait(&semaphores[iTo]);

  mailboxes[iTo] = Msg;

  sem_post(&semaphores[iTo]);

  return 0;
}

int RecvMsg(int iFrom, struct msg &Msg) {

  sem_wait(&semaphores[iFrom]);

  if (safeToCall(iFrom)) {
    cout << "Error calling RecvMsg" << endl;
    return 1;
  }

  mailboxes[iFrom] = Msg;

  sem_post(&semaphores[iFrom]);

  return 0;
}

bool safeToCall(int location) {
  bool safe = !(location < 0 || location > MAXTHREAD + 1);
  return safe;
  //return true;
}
```

mailbox.h

```
#ifndef MAILBOX_H_
#define MAILBOX_H_

#define RANGE 1
#define ALLDONE 2

#define MAXTHREAD 10


#include <semaphore.h>
#include <pthread.h>

struct msg {
  int iSender; /* sender of the message (0 .. numThreads)*/
  int type; /* its type */
  int value1; /* first value */
  int value2; /* second value */
};

struct msg mailboxes[MAXTHREAD + 1];
pthread_t threads[MAXTHREAD + 1];
sem_t semaphores[MAXTHREAD + 1];

int SendMsg(int iTo, struct msg &Msg);
int RecvMsg(int iFrom, struct msg &Msg);
bool safeToCall(int location);


#endif
```

I am compiling the code with the command

```
g++ -o addem addem.cpp mailbox.cpp -lpthread
```

I have tried commenting out all of the function bodies in the source code to leave them as stub functions, and the same error occurs. The only way I have been able to compile the file is if I comment out the function bodies, and remove

```
#include "mailbox.h"
```

From at least one of the files. I feel it has to do with how I am initializing the arrays? But I cannot figure out a workaround.

Comment: Use `extern` to declare those arrays in the header file, and add a definition in your .cpp file.

Comment: Which .cpp file? Both of them access the arrays

Comment: Choose one (and only one) of them, it doesn't matter. If you feel it's wrong to define them in one of them, create another one, and define your arrays there.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much for taking the time to help, you made my day!